# Logger in Flask application has stopped logging to console

Tags: python, flask, logging

I recently set up logging in my Flask app such that it would log to files and stdout. I was inserting logging statements like

```
current_app.logger.info('Logging message')
```

into routes so that I could see logging messages when I ran pytest tests on the routes. This worked (logged to the files and console) for a little while, but at some point it stopped logging to the console while continuing to log to the log files.

I'm not sure what could have caused logging to stdout to stop. The only thing that comes to mind is that I attempted to add a logging statement to the test module at one point. This caused an error, which may have had something to do with the logger not being configured in the app defined by my application factory pytest fixture. However, I've since deleted this logging statement from the test module, and I'm still not getting the console logs that I got previously.

Can anyone see any reason why logging to the console would have stopped?

My logging configuration:

```
__init__.py:

def create_app(test_config=None):

    app = Flask('project_name', instance_relative_config=True)

    ...

    if not app.debug:
        if not os.path.exists('logs'):
            os.mkdir('logs')
        file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/trivia.log', maxBytes=10240, backupCount=10)
        file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        stream_handler = StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
            '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'
        ))
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        app.logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

        app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

```
routes.py

@bp.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_question():
    current_app.logger.info("Received request to /add")
    ...
```

Comment: Are you sure you are logging with the correct level? I the code you show, you are using `current_app.logger.debug` but the level is set to `INFO`. Debug is below info, so it won't show up

Comment: Good spot. That was one of a few logging statements though, some of which are `INFO`. That statement in particular isn't working when I change it to info. Edited the post to avoid confusion; thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because logging messages only get displayed in the console when a pytest test fails. My tests were all passing for a while, so I wasn't seeing the logging messages.